# Eclipse - overloaded method not recognize

Tags: java, eclipse

This is really strange, the method parseXHtml is overloaded and argument list (PdfWriter, Document, InputStreamReader, InputStreamReader) exists.  I have checked javadoc, decompile the jar etc., it's there!  But eclipse just won't load the correct one!

> The method parseXHtml(PdfWriter, Document, InputStream, Charset) in the type XMLWorkerHelper is not applicable for the arguments (PdfWriter, Document, InputStreamReader, InputStreamReader)

```
    public void parseXHtml(PdfWriter writer, Document doc, InputStream in, InputStream inCssFile) throws IOException
    {
       parseXHtml(writer, doc, in, inCssFile, null, ((FontProvider) (new XMLWorkerFontProvider())));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The last two arguments of `parseXHtml` are of type `InputStream` and `Charset` respectively:

```
parseXHtml(PdfWriter, Document, InputStream, Charset)
```

Change the method arguments as this:

```
public void parseXHtml(PdfWriter writer, Document doc, InputStream in, Charset charset) throws IOException
    {
     ...
    }
```

Comment: the "illusion" of implicit casting, lol...  Your answer is of course correct, so is the one above.